# For-each through rows -1 in xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a question regarding xslt:

basically i have filtered rows:

```
<xsl:variable name="filteredRows" select="TestRows[(contains(@*[name()='FieldName'],@Title))]" />
```

And now i want to do for each on them but -1 so if there are 3 rows i want to execute for each only twice ... how to do that?

```
<xsl:for-each select ="$filteredRows - 1">
    <xsl:text> label =  </xsl:text>EMPTY
    <br />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Thanks for help ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested (you didn't provide any sample), but `<xsl:for-each select ="$filteredRow[position() &lt; last()]">` could work.